# Format': is not a member of 'CStatic' Timers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

```
void CTimersDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    CTime curTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime();

    m_sTime.Format("%d:%d:%d",curTime.GetHour(),curTime.GetMinute(),curTime.GetSecond());
    
    // Update the dialog
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    CDialogEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Comment: Your post doesn't contain a question, and your code is incomplete. What is `m_sTime`? Please [edit] your question, add some explanation and a question and create a [mre].

Comment: Format is a member of CString

Comment: In this particular case the error message is clear and explains the problem. It seems that yiu have mapped your control to a control variable instead of a value variablke. This affects the type of variable created. For example, static text will map to a CStatic control or a CString value. You choose when you create the control. You need to learn about the basics of the resource editor and working with the variables.

Comment: This isn't a feature of the resource editor. It is a feature of the MFC library, namely [Dialog Data Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange). *Every* feature exposed by the resource editor is ultimately reflected in code. In this case it is one of the [Standard Dialog Data Exchange Routines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines), specifically `DDX_Control` or `DDX_Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MFC, you can create two kinds of variables associated with a `STATIC`: `control` with a type of `CStatic` (as you have) and `value` with a type of `CString`.

You tagged `visual-studio-code` - is that what you are using? If you are using `Visual Studio`, I suggest to use a wizard: right-click on your `STATIC` control in the dialog (in the Resource Editor) and select `Add Variable...`. In the `Category` dropbox select `Value`. You will be able to call `.Format()` on that variable.

You could create both kinds of variables for the same control, not sure if you need that.